# Seaborn: how to make subplots with multiple line charts? sns.relplot doesn't seem to support it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The seaborn documentation makes a distinction between figure-level and axes-level functions: https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html#figure-level-and-axes-level-functions

I understand that functions like sns.boxplot can take an axis as argument, and can therefore be used within subplots.

But how about sns.relplot() ? Is there no way to put that into subplots?

More generally, is there any way to get seaborn to generate line plots within subplots?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2)
sns.relplot(x,y, ax=ax[0])
```

because relplot doesn't take axes as an argument.

Comment: The existing solution on this page no longer works. sns.relplot is a figure-level plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's not true. You can indeed pass axis objects to `relplot`. Below is a minimal answer. The key point here is to *close the empty axis objects* returned by `relplot`. You can then also use `ax[0]` or `ax[1]` to add additional curves to your individual subfigures just like you would do with `matplotlib`.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)

xdata = np.arange(50)

sns.set(style="ticks")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g1 = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", data=tips, ax=ax[0])
g2 = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", data=tips, ax=ax[1])

# Now you can add any curves to individual axis objects 
ax[0].plot(xdata, xdata/5) 

# You will have to close the additional empty figures returned by replot
plt.close(g1.fig)
plt.close(g2.fig) 
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

You can also make line plot solely using `seaborn` as

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = x**2

ax = sns.lineplot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('x-label')
ax.set_ylabel('y-label')
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I can imagine the argument for doing so being the following: A `relplot` is a figure level seaborn function. It is meant to create a FacetGrid of several line- or scatterplots. Now if you only have a single axes in that grid, there is no need for `relplot` anyways and you can (should) directly use either `lineplot` or `scatterplot`. And if you had more than one axes in the grid, the solution would not work anyways, because `ax` is not an argument to `relplot` itself, it's an argument to the underlying line- or scatterplot function.

Comment: `UserWarning: relplot is a figure-level function and does not accept target axes. You may wish to try scatterplot warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)`

Comment: As for 2023, `ax` is not an argument for `relplot` now it can be used with `lineplot` similarly as the answer above